# Magento Enterprise url rewrite in observer

Tags: event-observer, url-rewrite

We tried to implement this scenario in ee 1.13: we have a custom product attribute (new_edition_id), when a product is saved, if this attribute is set, we want to create a url rewrite from current product to the product with attribute id equals to new_edition_id.
We've implemented it in an observer using this snippet of code:

```
$rewrite = Mage::getModel('enterprise_urlrewrite/url_rewrite');
      $rewrite->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->setOptions('RP')
        ->setIdentifier($requestPath)
        ->setTargetPath($targetPath)
        ->setRequestPath($requestPath)
        ->setDescritpion('Nuova Edizione plugin')
        ->setProductId($product->getId())
        ->save();
```

The result is that some records are inserted in enterprise url rewrite tables, but from the front end redirections doesn't work.
Any suggestion?

Thanks
Ruggero

Comment: Did you tried reindexing after the process? You can also add the reindex to the observer if it works.

Comment: Yes, I tried; I've also disabled Magento Cache